# Icon inside Toolbar is not clickable

Tags: android

This is my main.xml file--

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.pawan.googlesignin.SongsActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="live music" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="scheduled" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /></RelativeLayout>
```

This is my items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:title="feedback"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:title="profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

This is my MainActivity.xml--

```
public class SongsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewpager;
private Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:starting");
    mSectionPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewpager =findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewpager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);
    toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My app");

}



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, VenuesActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter=new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new live(),"live music");
    adapter.addFragment(new scheduled(),"scheduled");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

[image]

Friends, I am not able to click on the back navigation button and also on the three dots on the top right corner of the Toolbar.
Please give a solution for this, I have tried all the solutions on provided here.
I can't find any error here.Please help me...

Comment: if you want an icon on the toolbar is clickable you can set image view inside a toolbar, and apply click listener normally

Comment: If there's absolutely no visual feedback when you click on those items, then there's likely something in your layout that's covering the `Toolbar`.

Comment: Ofcourse you are right, there is no visual feedback and so i have updated the Main.xml file also, please check it  @Mike

Comment: have you solved your issue ? @PAWANLAKHOTIA

Comment: No brother, no solutions found yet.

Comment: Hmm, I'd've thought the `ViewPager` would cover the `AppBarLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` like that, but I just did a quick test, and it doesn't, for some reason. I'll have to figure that out later, but, for now, you might try setting `android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"` on the `<ViewPager>`, since there's apparently some weirdness going on there already.

Comment: THANKS A LOT @MikeM. THIS WORKED FOR ME

Comment: Ah, good. Yeah, that's really odd. I'm not sure what's going on with that layout, but somehow the `AppBarLayout` acts very unexpectedly there. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

in my case :

changing activity_main.xml from this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/asset_bar_layout"/>
```

to this:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead to handle the back button on the actionbar.

```
case android.R.id.home:
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    return true;
```

Comment: even with this there is no effect on my android phone emulator...please also check the Main.xml file which i have updated.

Answer (score -1):

> Hello,i have find the solution for your query
>
> Please update your code like this

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            System.out.println("back button pressed");

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.share:
            System.out.println("share button pressed");
        case R.id.feedback:
            System.out.println("feedback button pressed");
        case R.id.profile:
            System.out.println("profile button pressed");
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You have forgot to call `finish()`method and defining the click listener of your menu item.
Please ask me if you need any more help.

Comment: sorry bro, even this is not working for me actually there is not at any visual effect when i click on these icons. Any other solutions??? also ask me if any other part of my code is required.

Comment: Are you able to send code on my gmail id jaidwivedi20@gmail.com